# How can I install WLAN drivers on Fedora 17 without any internet access?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers

I need to install WLAN drivers for my "Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card" on my PC
without using LAN, because my LAN slot broke.
 I am a Linux noob btw.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need these packages:

```
kmod-wl-5.100.82.112-2.fc17.11.i686.rpm
kmod-wl-3.3.4-5.fc17.i686-5.100.82.112-2.fc17.11.i686.rpm
broadcom-wl-5.100.82.112-2.fc17.1.noarch.rpm
```

They can be downloaded from http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/releases/17/Everything/i386/os/

Download them on a computer that has internet, and then put them on a CD/USB stick and copy them to your computer. Then do:

```
su -C 'yum localinstall kmod-wl-5.100.82.112-2.fc17.11.i686.rpm kmod-wl-3.3.4-5.fc17.i686-5.100.82.112-2.fc17.11.i686.rpm broadcom-wl-5.100.82.112-2.fc17.1.noarch.rpm'
su -C '/sbin/modprobe wl'
```

Then see if it works.